# T-SQL TRY-CATCH not working in DDL trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl

I have a DDL trigger to audit any changes to DDL events that occur on the server.

The code in the trigger reads the eventdata and writes it to a table.

I want to wrap that operation in a TSQL try-catch so if it fails for any reason then I would log the fault to the SQL log but let the operation go through, but it doesn't seem to work.
I am already using if exists to make sure the table I need to write to still exists, but I want to trap any unforseen errors and make the trigger as robust as possible.

DDL triggers seem to work differently than normal T-SQL and doesn't seem to honour the TRY-CATCH block.

The following code works fine if it is in an SP but it doesn't work if it is in a DDL trigger.

```
BEGIN TRY
-- Simulate an error
RAISERROR ('Just a test!', 14, 1);
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
DECLARE @errorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER()
DECLARE @errorMessage NVARCHAR(2048) = ERROR_MESSAGE() + '('
    + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS NVARCHAR) + ')'

-- Log the error to the SQL server event log
EXEC master..xp_logevent 50005, @errorMessage, WARNING
END CATCH;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8693/why-try-catch-does-not-suppress-exception-in-trigger

Comment: In my experience using `CATCH`, if you don't `THROW` an error within the catch, it will perform whatever you specify in the catch block but won't, say, mark a job as failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use xp logevent from triggers http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186244.aspx
Look at remarks for reasons